Set new trace Id for each loop iteration instead of using existing trace id
I have a spring boot 3.1.x application with dependency on micrometer-tracing and micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel libraries.
There is a service bean that sends multiple http requests to a different service. With RestTemplate bean created using RestTemplateBuilder, I can see that the traceId from my service is sent to service#2 in the traceparent request header.
Lets consider this code.
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder){
        return builder.build();
    }
}




@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(){
        log.info("received request");

        for (int i =0; i < 3; i++){
            log.info("submitting request");
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/hello", String.class );
            log.info("submitted request");
        }

        log.info("done with all requests");

        return "hello";
    }
}

Issue is that the same traceId value is used for all 3 requests sent from service#1 to service#2. This is causing issues with uniquely identifying all the logs from a specific request on service#2 and it's downstream dependencies.
I would like to send a different traceId for each request from service#1. In essence, I want to start a new trace within each iteration of the for loop. So any logs inside the loop and the traceparent header sent to service#2 will be new value. And once the for loop ends, remaining logs in the execution should havee the original trace context.

This is by design, you can use the spanId to identify certain operations but the spans in your scenario must share the same traceId since they belong together.
